# Red5 test page won't come up

Tags: windows-server-2008, red5

I successfully installed red5 rc1 on windows server 2008 with these parameters:

```
127.0.0.1 port 5080
```

as per tutorials.

I execute the `StartRed5-NT.bat` since it is an NT os... and it gives me Red5 Has Started output. 
when i try to then type

```
127.0.0.1:5080 
localhost:5080

 or even its externalIP:5080
```

into a web browser address, i get 404 errors.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong that's preventing me to run the test page?  I am assuming if the test page doesn't work the server does not work either.

Edit:  I have reinstalled a few times and  tried other ports with no effective change.  Even some of the ports that were used for other services were temporarily disabled to try that port but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution after going through the logs VERY carefully.
to get this to work,(at least on windows 7 and windows server 2008) 
the red5.bat must look like this:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL

if NOT DEFINED RED5_HOME set RED5_HOME=%~dp0

if NOT DEFINED RED5_MAINCLASS set RED5_MAINCLASS=org.red5.server.Bootstrap

if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto err

REM JAVA options
REM You can set JAVA_OPTS to add additional options if you want
REM Set up logging options
set LOGGING_OPTS=-Dlogback.ContextSelector=org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true
REM Set up security options
REM set SECURITY_OPTS= -Djava.security.debug=failure -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy="%RED5_HOME%/conf/red5.policy"
set SECURITY_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=failure
set JAVA_OPTS=%LOGGING_OPTS% %SECURITY_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS%

set JYTHON_OPTS=-Dpython.home=lib

set RED5_CLASSPATH=%RED5_HOME%\boot.jar;%RED5_HOME%\conf;%CLASSPATH%

if NOT DEFINED RED5_OPTS set RED5_OPTS=

goto launchRed5

:launchRed5
echo Starting Red5
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JYTHON_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% -cp "%RED5_CLASSPATH%" %RED5_MAINCLASS% %RED5_OPTS%
goto finally

:err
echo JAVA_HOME environment variable not set! Take a look at the readme.
pause

:finally
ENDLOCAL
```

then proceed to delete two files:

```
com.springsource.slf4j.juli-1.6.1.jar
com.springsource.slf4j.log4j-1.6.1.jar
```

this may only apply to the windows installer version of the application but hopefully if someone hits this, they won't need to waste a lot of time on it.